# Group by a value of an object, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of objects, and I want to group by "round_number".

```
$data = AnswerHistory::select(
    'answer_histories.round_number',
    'answer_histories.answer_time',
    'questions.free_text as question_free_text',
    'lkp_answers.name as answer_name',
    'paragraphs.free_text as paragraph_free_text',
    )
    ->orderBy('answer_histories.id', 'DESC')
    ->where('answer_histories.user_id', 1)
    ->whereNotNull('answer_histories.lkp_answer_id')
    ->leftJoin('questions','answer_histories.question_id','questions.id')
    ->leftJoin('lkp_answers','answer_histories.lkp_answer_id','lkp_answers.id')
    ->leftJoin('paragraphs','answer_histories.paragraph_id','paragraphs.id')
    ->get()->toArray();


     //I tried this, but I get only 1 value for each round_number
     $new_array = array();
     foreach ($data as $item)
      if (!array_key_exists($item['round_number'], $new_array))
         $new_array[$item['round_number']] = $item;
```

**This is the output:**

[image]

Comment: use this ```->get()->groupBy('round_number')->toArray()``` instead of this ```->get()->toArray();```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this `->get()->groupBy('round_number')->toArray()` instead of this `->get()->toArray();`

Comment: 10 min count down, until stack-overflow will let me.